# Unit test pyspark and accumulator

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, pytest

I'm trying to test my Spark code in Python but I'm whenever my test code runs, all my accumulators are empty. However, when I run the code locally without mocks, the code works fine and the accumulators have values. Here's a trimmed down version of the code:

Code:

```py
from typing import Any
from pyspark.accumulators import AccumulatorParam
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame, SparkSession

columns: Any = []

class SetAccumulator(AccumulatorParam):
    def zero(self, value):
        return value.copy()

    def addInPlace(self, value1, value2):
        return value1.union(value2)

def read_columns(obj: dict) -> None:
    global columns

    for key in obj.keys():
        columns += {key}

def run(spark: SparkSession, df: DataFrame) -> list:
    global columns
    columns = spark.sparkContext.accumulator(set(), SetAccumulator())
    df.rdd.foreach(lambda row: read_columns(row.asDict()))
    return list(columns.value)
```

Mock Spark test code:

```py
import pydeequ
from unittest import TestCase
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

class SparkTestCase(TestCase):
    spark: SparkSession

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls) -> None:
        cls.spark = (
            SparkSession.builder.appName("testspark")
              .master("local")
              .enableHiveSupport()
              .config("spark.jars.packages", pydeequ.deequ_maven_coord)
              .config("spark.jars.excludes", pydeequ.f2j_maven_coord)
              .config("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", 8)
              .getOrCreate()
        )
```

Test code:

```py
from tests.spark.testcase import SparkTestCase
from foo.bar import run

class TestFoo(SparkTestCase):
    def test_foo(self):
        columns = [
            "test",
            "bar",
            "name"
        ]
        data = [
            (
                "Hello!",
                100,
                "Foobar"
            )
        ]

        df = self.spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)
        response = run(self.spark, df)
        print(response)
```

The test prints out an empty list. But as mentioned, when I run this outside of the testing framework (locally, on my computer), it prints out `["test", "bar", "name"]`.

What am I doing wrong or what do I need to add to make it work in the test case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out one way to make the unit test work. I created a dictionary of the accumulators and passed that to each task and the test was able to update the values correctly. I'm assuming `global` doesn't work correctly with Spark unit tests.

Here's what the updated code looks like. The test code from the question above remains the same.

```py
from typing import Any
from pyspark.accumulators import AccumulatorParam
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame, SparkSession

class SetAccumulator(AccumulatorParam):
    def zero(self, value):
        return value.copy()

    def addInPlace(self, value1, value2):
        return value1.union(value2)

def read_columns(obj: dict, accumulators: dict) -> None:
    for key in obj.keys():
        accumulators["columns"] += {key}

def run(spark: SparkSession, df: DataFrame) -> list:
    columns = spark.sparkContext.accumulator(set(), SetAccumulator())
    accumulators = {"columns": columns}
    df.rdd.foreach(lambda row: read_columns(row.asDict(), accumulators))
    return list(columns.value)
```

I removed the `columns` variable on the top and removed all global references to it. Instead, I created a dictionary `accumulators = {"columns": columns}`, which I pass to the `read_columns` function and get the accumulator by key.

The test correctly prints out `["test", "bar", "name"]` now and it still works outside of the test environment.